# Can scratches be shared between IntelliJ and Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I'm working on a project in Android Studio 3.1.  I first had to create a .jar file with dependancies in IntelliJ 2017.2.  I chose to do my programming in the IntelliJ IDE because I knew that Android Studio is based on IntelliJ.

But now I have a bunch of scratches (lots of notes and code) for my project that I assumed would be available in Android Studio, but they are  not.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio to use the scratches from IntelliJ?  I will have to be jumping back and forth more and more between IDE's in the future as the project develops.

Comment: I have found that Android Studio is storing scratches in /Users/terry/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.1/scratches/ directory while IntelliJ is storing scratches in /Users/terry/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2017.2/scratches.  I found that you can right click on the scratches list and choose "reveal in finder" (Mac) to see where the scratches are being stored.  But I have not found a way to tell the IDE to change what directory it uses for storing scratches, besides manually copying or linking a directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's is possible to specify a [location for scratches](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159157) using `Help | Edit Custom Properties...` and adding the following property there:

```
idea.scratch.path=~/Scratches
```

It is necessary to restart the IDE after you make changes there. You could specify the same location in both IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio. (You can of course choose your own path/location.) In this directory two further directories will be created by the IDE, "scratches" and "consoles". You can create these directories yourself if you already have scratches you wish to use.

Comment: Nicely Answered!  That was exactly what I was looking for.  I was going to ask how you found that answer, because none of my searches brought it up, even after I searched on your answer.  Thank you for the link to the youtrack site.  I was worried that there was a manual that I was missing.  In addition, I just wanted to add that you must exit the IntelliJ or Android Studio *completely* in order for the change to take affect.  That part threw me for a little bit.  Thanks you again for the answer.

Comment: You're right, I have added some text about restarting for future readers. The answer was found by luck. I was actually looking for issues about a different problem with scratches:-)

Comment: in case more "explicate" example is needed (on win) :

`idea.scratch.path/scratches=C:/DEV/pycharm_settings/scratches`